# Multiple values at $response

Tags: php, html, submit

On my HTML file i have the following:

```
First Name <input type="text" name="username" size=100>
Last Name  <input type="text" name="lastname" size=100>
```

when i submit this page i have the following at the php file:

```
 $_username = $_POST['username'];
 $_lastname = $_POST['lastname'];

 $response = $_Client->doHallo($_username);
 echo $response;
```

How can i add both the username and the lastname at the $response line?

Comment: *"How can i add both the username and the lastname at the $response line?"* - Concatenate?

Comment: Whatever! I just want to display username AND lastname!

Comment: `$_Client->doHallo($_username . $_lastname);`

Comment: What do you mean "Whatever!" ? - I told you what to do and that's what you needed to do. Never heard the term before? Plus, Nikolay even gave you an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this `$response = $_Client->doHallo($_username.' '.$_lastname);`.

Comment: Thanks mate that really helped! If i want to add more i just continue the sequence?

Comment: You welcome, yes, you can continue the sequence as much as you want.